# if col1 has the same data, copy col2 data

Tags: sql-server

I want to check col1, and if there's 2 of the same in col1, copy the value in col2 that's != 0 to the col2 that is 0. The data comes in from an Excel file that I can't alter. See example below

Input

```
+----------+-------+
| prime    |   %   |
+----------+-------+
| a1       |   3   |
| a1       |   0   |
| b2       |   25  |
| b3       |   42  |
| c4       |   23  |
| c4       |   0   |
+----------+-------+
```

Output

```
+----------+-------+
| prime    |   %   |
+----------+-------+
| a1       |   3   |
| a1       |   3   |
| b2       |   25  |
| b3       |   42  |
| c4       |   23  |
| c4       |   23  |
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: What happens if there are 3 values for c4 in `col1`, all with different values in `col2` (say 0, 43 and 27)?  Which one do you want to keep?

Comment: that will never happen, in excel, if the prime is the same, the % is the same. the reason its loaded as 0 is because the excel uses merged cells

Comment: And the version of your SQL Server is...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution gives you the desired output.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
    (
      Prime CHAR(2) NOT NULL
    , Percentage INT NOT NULL
    );

INSERT  INTO @TempTable
        ( Prime, Percentage )
VALUES  ( 'a1', 3 )
    ,   ( 'a1', 0 )
    ,   ( 'b2', 25 )
    ,   ( 'b3', 42 )
    ,   ( 'c4', 23 )
    ,   ( 'c4', 0 );

WITH CTE_NonZero
    AS ( SELECT   T.Prime
                , MAX(T.Percentage) AS PercentageToUse
        FROM     @TempTable T
        WHERE T.Percentage <> 0
        GROUP BY T.Prime
        )
    UPDATE  @TempTable
    SET     Percentage = P.PercentageToUse
    FROM    @TempTable T
            INNER JOIN CTE_NonZero P ON P.Prime = T.Prime
    WHERE   T.Percentage = 0;

SELECT * FROM    @TempTable;
```

Alternatively, you could make the CTE updatable and thus avoid the join:

```
WITH MaxPercentages
    AS ( SELECT   T.Percentage
                , MAX(T.Percentage) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Prime) AS PercentageToUse
        FROM     @TempTable T
        )
    UPDATE  MaxPercentages
    SET     Percentage = PercentageToUse
    WHERE   Percentage = 0 AND PercentageToUse <> 0;
```

Comment: how do i do it without setting the value (VALUES  ('a1', 3) , ('a1', 0) , ('b2', 25) , ('b3', 42) , ('c4', 23) , ('c4', 0)). the table already has values in them.

Comment: Start with the ";WITH CTE_NonZero"... line, remove everything above it.  Then change where @TempTable to the name of your table.    I would definitely test it before using in production.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this assumes that `Percentage` cannot be negative. That's probably a valid assumption given the column name, but it's not explicitly mentioned one way or the other in the question.

Comment: @JonathanFite instead of adding statement terminators (`;`) only in front of `WITH`, it would be better to add them at the end of all statements. Microsoft recommends so: *"[`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it **will be required in a future version**.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)"*

Comment: [I've blogged about statement terminators, too](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons). I thought it would start catching on six years later, but I fear people are more concerned about being 8 microseconds more productive today than how much time they'll spend fixing code tomorrow.

Comment: @ypercube, Aaron Bertrand.  I know, it's a bad habit of mine.  I can't seem to get into the habit of including statement terminators.  I do know that it's going to be deprecated, but I honestly think that will be the only thing that will force me to change, having it just not work unless they are included.  I do tend to pass most of my code through Red Gates SQL Prompt which appends the statement terminators for me.

Answer (score 2):

This query gives you the correct output:

```
create table #data (prime char(2), pct int)
insert into #data(prime, pct) values
    ('a1', 3)
    , ('a1', 0)
    , ('b2', 25)
    , ('b3', 42)
    , ('c4', 23)
    , ('c4', 0)

Update d1 set pct = d2.pct
From #data d1
Inner Join #data d2 on d2.prime = d1.prime
Where d1.pct = 0 and d2.pct <> 0

Select * From #data
```

Output:

```
prime   pct
a1      3
a1      3
b2      25
b3      42
c4      23
c4      23
```

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, why produce duplicates instead of removing them?

```
select Prime, max(Percentage) as Percentage from <yourTable> group by Prime
```

Comment: because although the prime and % are the same, the brand is different and i need that to reflect

Comment: There is no brand in the sample data. Is there anything else you are not telling us?

Comment: the post i selected as the answer was able achieve what i was asking for without the brand, not sure what your looking for

Comment: That's fine then

Comment: @lizzy91: Mister Magoo's solution makes perfect sense with regard to the question as posted. It only becomes irrelevant when you reveal details that you never mentioned in your question. So the reason he was asking for "anything else" was to avoid wasting his time again because of something important that might once again invalidate his suggestion (as your mentioning another column has done). This all may not matter much for this particular question but please be more considerate next time when presenting your problem – do not oversimplify it.

Comment: i wasn't trying to oversimplify it. i (imo) gave enough data to get what i needed done. he asked why produce duplicates instead of removing it, so i answered why, but the why had nothing to do with the question i asked (i hope that makes sense). sorry @MisterMagoo if i came off as rude or inconsiderate it was not my intentions.

Comment: No problem lizzy91, I didn't see it as rude. The point that @Andridy made is valid though - that you left out important information (to you) that excludes certain approaches to the problem. We can't see what you see, so it could be thought of as a "waste of our time". In this case it was only a tiny amount of time, so not a problem, but there are cases where the information dribbles out and makes it very hard to help the OP.